# ADFv2: creating data source with a dynamic authenticated URL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that uses a Lookup activity with a POST REST service as the source dataset.  This Lookup successfully retrieves a string from the body that is then passed as an "access token" inside the header of GET Web activity.

This GET Web activity then returns a set of 3 values inside the body of the return: fileURL, sasToken, fileaccessURL.  The "fileaccessURL" is simply a concatenation of "fileURL" and "sasToken"

The new dynamically created "fileaccessurl" points to a ZIP file inside a blob storage housed with my partner company.  This ZIP file contains that actual data I want to use as my data source. I am OK with deflating the file once I get it and using the files within as my actual source.

The issue I'm having is how to specify that the dynamically assigned "fileaccessurl" is my data source for getting that initial ZIP file?  I can't parameterize REST or HTTP linked services or figure out any other way to set this.  I have already eliminated the option of connecting directly to the partner blob storage.  I have tried using lookups but I still can't figure out how to specify my destination with a URL that isn't necessarily always the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to parameterize linked service, you can try to use the advanced part and check "specify dynamic content in JSON format".

[image]

This is the sample JSON code:

```
{
    "name": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "value": "Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=@{linkedService().DBName};User ID=user;Password=fake;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30",
                "type": "SecureString"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": null,
        "parameters": {
            "DBName": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to modify the code to align with Rest or HTTP linked service payload.